# How to synchronize readings with the HIGH and LOW states of a PWM output?

Tags: microcontroller, pwm, embedded

I would like to oscillate GPIO infrared LEDs at a high frequency and compare the infrared sensor readings when the LEDs are off and when they are on. To do this I would need to synchronize the readings with the PWM. Currently, I can use a pseudo-PWM by using digitalWrite to toggle them between HIGH and LOW with a delay to take readings, but this only give me 500Hz.

How can I synchronize readings with a PWM output? Or should I just use another method of digital on/off?

Comment: Since you mention digitalWrite I will assume that you are using an Arduino. That's vital information so please add a complete description of your hardware. Also, if 500Hz means "only" to you, what frequency do you need? What range of duty factor?

Comment: Do you have any specs for expected dynamic range of background to peak IR and detector ON/OFF emitter decay time and desired commutation rate? Surely making a variable relaxation clock is trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you'd probably want to use the PWM peripheral on the MCU chip and generate an interrupt from the PWM peripheral, then make the ADC measurement (or at least trigger it to begin) in the interrupt service routine. The details, such as which PWM mode to use, and how well it will work depends a lot on the chip. Worst case, you could wire the PWM output back to an interrupt input. You may also need a delay to allow the ADC input to settle after the LED state changes, so perhaps another timer would be involved depending on exactly when in the PWM cycle the interrupt is generated (check out phase-correct PWM if you're using an ATmega328).

Your use of the term digitalWrite implies you're trying to do this with some Arduino or Arduino-like module, so you'll have to study the underlying chip (eg. Atmega328) features and how to use interrupts.

You may be able to get more specific help in the Arduino forum.

Comment: This may or may not be feasible though, depending on how much the program is otherwise doing. An interrupt on each edge of a PWM will consume lots of the available CPU and needs to be benchmarked to finish quickly. ADC conversion rate will be a bottleneck.

Comment: @Lundin The Atmega328 takes as little as 13us for a conversion (equivalent to more than 2 orders of magnitude higher than OP is getting now), and the conversion can occur *concurrently* with CPU activity so I don't think it will be particularly limiting. Probably the Arduino libraries will be most limiting, assuming that's what OP is using. Using inline code in the interrupt(s) may make much of that moot.

Comment: Even if you use bare metal assembler with no function calls, you must start the conversion inside the ISR and wait for it to finish. Depending on duty cycle, there might not be much time left - the real-time aspects of these kind of control systems with PWM+ADC are very tough. Arduino is of course the wrong tool for the task since it is so code inefficient.

Comment: @Lundin I would start the ADC conversion in one ISR and retrieve the result in the next.